# Tail-Recursion in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I'm new to Prolog and I'm having trouble with a practise question on tail recursion.

Question:

> Define a relationship, where the first argument is a list of objects, the second is a number, and the third is the total price of the objects in the list plus the second argument; and also ensure that the call to the recursion is the last clause of your rule.
>
> Object list:
>
> ```erlang
> cost( table, 1000).  
> cost( chair, 100).  
> cost( lamp, 80).  
> cost( oven, 800).
> ```

e.g. `totalTail( [chair,table], 100, X)` ==> `X = 1200`.

What rules should I be defining?

Comment: a penny for your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You can start by defining what you already know it ought to be:

```
totalTail( [chair, table], 100, X) :- X = 1200.
```

or, equivalently,

```
totalTail( [Chair, Table], 100, X) :- 
    Chair = chair, cost( Chair, 100),
    Table = table, cost( Table, 1000),
    X is 100 + 100 + 1000.
```

or, equivalently,

```
totalTail( [Chair, Table], InitialCost, X) :- InitialCost = 100,
    Chair = chair, cost( Chair, ChairCost), ChairCost = 100,
    Table = table, cost( Table, TableCost), TableCost = 1000,
    X is InitialCost + ChairCost + TableCost.
```

or, equivalently,

```
totalTail( [Chair, Table], InitialCost, X) :- 
                   cost( Chair, ChairCost),
                   cost( Table, TableCost),
    X is InitialCost + ChairCost + TableCost.
```

(**Boom!**) *Or, equivalently,*

```
totalTail( [A, B], InitialCost, X) :- 
                   cost( A, ACost),
                   cost( B, BCost),
    X is InitialCost + ACost + BCost.
```

or even

```
totalTail( [A, B, C], Z, X) :- 
                   cost( A, ACost),
                   cost( B, BCost),
                   cost( C, CCost),
    X is Z + ACost + BCost + CCost.
```

which *is* the same as

```
totalTail( [A, B, C], Z, X) :- 
                   cost( A, ACost),
                   totalTail( [B, C], Z, X2)
    X is Z + ACost + X2.
```

Right? Wrong! Can you spot the error? Did we count something twice, there?

So fixing it, we get

```
totalTail( [A, B, C], Z, X) :- 
                   cost( A, ACost),
                   Z2 is .... + .... ,
                   totalTail( [B, C], Z2, X).
```

Right. But isn't it the same as

```
totalTail( [A | BC], Z, X) :- BC = [B, C],
                   cost( A, ACost),
                   Z2 is .... + .... ,
                   totalTail( BC, Z2, X).
```

But, again, why limit yourself to that very specific option, `BC = [B, C]`? Do we really have to specify it?

And what if the first argument does not match the `[A | BC]` list at all? What kind of a list would that be? And what should `X` be in that case?

Comment: You do need to write "The little Prologer"

Comment: thanks, I'll think about it. :) careful though, this road leads to all the (web) programmers of the world replaced by a machine, as it ought to have been done all those decades ago. I mean, if the specification is already written, why should a human being pour their *soul* into what ought to be a mundane mechanical derivation? (IOW train their one and only Gd-given neural net to do these tricks as though we were trained dogs or something (no disrespect to dogs)). that's the theory anyway, or rather a pipe dream.